# Import text with a specific delimiter into r

Tags: r

I want to load log events into a `data.table`, each log is identified by a `timestamp` and some logs can contains many lines.

I have the following `.txt` file :

```
2016-07-19 00:00:01,421 WARNING Exception happened while transfering for command
                                at java.lang.NumberFormatException
                                at java.lang.Integer.parseInt
                                at java.util.concurrent.Task

2016-07-19 00:01:01,525 DEBUG Upload all environments
2016-07-19 00:01:01,720 DEBUG Upload all environments
2016-07-19 00:02:00,520 WARNING Excpetion happened while transfering for command
                                at java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

I want to get the following `data.table` :

```
      log
1 2016-07-19 00:00:01,421 WARNING Exception happened while transfering for command at java.lang.NumberFormatException at java.lang.Integer.parseInt at java.util.concurrent.Task  
2 2016-07-19 00:01:01,525 DEBUG Upload all environments
3 2016-07-19 00:01:01,720 DEBUG Upload all environments
4 2016-07-19 00:02:00,520 WARNING Excpetion happened while transfering for command at java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

I want to upload each log event into a single line. I tried to use the `\n` separator :

```
docs <- read.table("log2.txt",header=FALSE,sep="\n",col.names="log",nrows=1000)
```

Comment: Try using `readLines` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `readLines` and then combine rows within `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)

raw = data.table(s = readLines('log.txt'))
raw = raw[s != '']
raw[, s := stringr::str_trim(s)]
raw[, idx := cumsum(s %like% '^[0-9]{4}')]
raw[, list(s = paste(s, collapse = ' ')), by = idx]
```

EDIT: changed year regex, thanks for the comment

Comment: This only works for the year 2016. Something like `'^[0-9]{4}'` would be better i guess

Comment: I already get each line as a row of my `data.table`, I shoud group line by `idx` value ?

Comment: `readLines` should return a character vector, each element is a row in your original data. if there are line breaks within a "log event" (that always start with the date / time) these will end up in different elements of the vector. `idx` is simply is a counter for these log events, then you can easily group by this counter and collapse the parts of each log event to one string.